# Artifactory: incremental backup: Not enough free space while there is enough space left

Tags: backup, artifactory

I've performed 2 backups of 2 repositories in Artifactory. They are incremental and they check avaible diskspace.

The first time the backups went well. They are 400GB and 150GB and they are saved in an NFS share.

Now when I manually start a second backup (incremental) I got the 'error':

```
Free space available for backup: 88170561536
Not enough free space to perform backup snapshots
```

There is still 82GB available. 550GB is taken. But I started an incremental backup on the smallest repo (150GB), there is maybe 100MB or something like that added (probably less).

Incremental = add only new added artifacts to existing backup, why is this not working or do I have to turn off the available disk space check in this case?

Edit: I tried to turn off the available disk space check but still I receive:  Not enough free space to perform backup releases.
After I've deleted all my backups and backup jobs, I recreated new backup jobs without checking the disk size before starting. The job was still complaining about a full disk till I enabled the option again. So now a backup is running again, but my incremental backup will never work. I've always to delete the full backup first.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly out of topic, but I got bitten by this calculation as well and this may be relevant to your question.

Say that you define you want a retention period that translates into a maximum of **n** backups on a storage location.
That means that your storage should be big enough to store at least **n + 1** backups (and not **n** as I would naively expect).

This is because the backup mechanism does the following

1. Check that the storage has enough space for one more backup
2. Do the actual backup
3. Check if any backup stored is more ancient that the retention period, and remove any backup that is out-of-date

As the cleanup is done after the current backup, size calculation is confusing.